# Effect size to minimum detectable effect

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, t-test, effect-size

I am running an A/B test for differences in customer revenue. More specifically, a t-test for the mean customer spend in my A and B groups. Before I launch my test, I would like to run an analysis that will tell me the smallest effect size I would be able to detect given a number of samples, power level, and significance level.

My question is: Is this a valid way to estimate minimum detectable effect?

1. Use a power solver like `statsmodels.stats.power.tt_ind_solve_power` to solve for `effect_size` given my expected samples, power level, and significance level. According to the function's documentation:

   - effect_size = difference in means / standard deviation
2. Convert `effect_size` to a dollar amount using historical estimates of the mean and standard deviation (standard deviation estimated for the number of samples I expect to collect)
3. Report this dollar amount as the minimum detectable effect given x samples, y power, and z alpha